# png24 to png8 conversion

Tags: python, image, png, imagemagick

I want to convert the input 24 bit PNG image to 8 bit, I have tried using Imagemagick and Python PIL, neither works.

for instance:

at Imagemagick I try convert console command as such:

```
convert -depth 8 png24image.png png8image.png
```

And here is the way I tried with python:

```
import Image
def convert_8bit(src, dest):
    """
    convert_8bit: String, String -> void.
    Converts the input image file into 8bit depth.
    """
    im = Image.open(src)
    if not im.mode == "P":
        im2 = im.convert("P", rgb2xyz)
        im2.save(dest)
```

Imagemagick doesn't even touch the image while the python function reduces to 8bit but keeps the number of unique numbers 164instead of 256. Photoshop used to convert the image to 8bit with 256unique numbers when converted to png8 from a 24 bit png image.

Thanks

EDIT:

**Output of 24->8 png conversion via Photoshop (which I need)**
[alt text http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/934/psout.png](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/934/psout.png)

**Converted via my Python function**

[alt text http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/6762/pythonout.png](http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/6762/pythonout.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't even touch the image" exactly? Does `png8image.png` not get created at all?

Comment: created but having no difference (just the same copy with another name)

Comment: *Hello I want to convert the input 24 bit PNG image to 8 bit, I have tried via Imagemagick and Python PIL but neither works.* should be *I want to convert the input 24 bit PNG image to 8 bit. I have tried using Imagemagick and Python PIL, but neither works.*

Comment: Do you want to go from 24 bits to 8 bits? In that case, edit the question title appropriately.

Comment: oh thanks for pointing it out Thomas, fixed :)

Comment: i don't get it... why should the number of colors be reduced to less than 256 in an 8 bit image?

Comment: Because it makes a 50kb difference for each image which has a 2mb original image :)

Comment: @Hellnar: have you, by chance mixed up your screen shots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the quantization method on the `convert` method isn't doing the right thing. Try this:

```
im2 = im.convert('RGB').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE)
```

The extra conversion to `RGB` may be redundant. I got this hint from http://nadiana.com/pil-tips-converting-png-gif

Comment: I have the impression that without the `palette=Image.ADAPTIVE` parameter, PIL uses only “web-safe” colours.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ, yes I think I saw that in the documentation somewhere. There's really no reason to use web-safe colors anymore - it was for a time when graphics adapters were much less capable. It results in a picture that looks bad and is less compressible too!

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this (using Imagick in PHP):

```
$colors = min(255, $im->getImageColors());
$im->quantizeImage($colors, Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB, 0, false, false );
$im->setImageDepth(8 /* bits */);
```

Comment: I use python and have very limited php knowledge thus the convert command version of this would be lovely :)

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick and PIL have [low quality PNG8 support](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=23340).

For best quality/filesize ratio (and full alpha support as a bonus) use [pngquant2](http://pngquant.org):

```
pngquant *.png
```